# what is the difference between 'sort -k1 file.txt' and 'sort -k1,1 file.txt'?

Tags: sorting, join

if a file contains multiple columns, seperated by comma, like this:

```
aaa,1,4,4,5,7
bbb,1,4,9,1,2
```

Is there difference between 'sort -t, -k1 file.txt' and 'sort -t, -k1,1 file.txt'? 
though with the example above, there is no difference, but in some of my project case, it
does has difference, but the difference is reflected in the case that I use the sorted file to join, and the join command throws out exception that 'join: file 2 is not in sorted order' (at that time , I use 'sort -t, -k1 file.txt') . Later I use 'sort -t, -k1,1 file.txt', and join command works well then. Can anybody tell me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sort -k1` means sort starting on key 1 till the end of the line. `sort -k1,1` means sort from key 1 to key 1 (so only the first key). On my machine, the two make a difference if I specify stable sort with `-s`:

```
~ $ cat test.txt
aaa,1,4,4,5,7
aaa,1,3,9,1,2

~ $ sort -t, -k1 -s test.txt
aaa,1,3,9,1,2
aaa,1,4,4,5,7

~ $ sort -t, -k1,1 -s test.txt
aaa,1,4,4,5,7
aaa,1,3,9,1,2
```

Comment: I have tried your sample, but if I do not use '-s' option, in 'sort -t, -k1,1 test.txt' , it will also sort according to the left key, so the result is the same as 'sort -t, -k1 test.txt'. Now I am confused why I specified using only key 1 to sort, but when encountering key 1 is the same of two lines, the sort command will automatically sort by the left key instead of lefting them the original order(because without -s option?), and that is not what I want. @Vlad the Impala

Comment: That is why the stable flag exists :) If you don't specify `-s`, you are not guaranteed a stable sort, which is what you are looking for I think. Use the `-s` flag if you want a stable sort.

Answer (score 2):

The second number is where the sort key *ends,* which defaults to the end of the line. From the manpage:

> **`-k, --key=POS1[,POS2]:`**
>   `start a key at POS1 (origin 1), end it at POS2 (default end of line)`

So, yes, there is a difference. Not in the case for your data since the `1,1` sort key has no duplicates.

But where you specify the `1,1` sort key, the two lines:

```
abc,plugh
abc,xyzzy
```

can sort in *either* order. With just `1` (meaning `1,end-of-line`), they'll sort in the order given.